# Micrometer Component in Apache Camel - Metric not showing in /actuator/prometheus

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, prometheus, micrometer

I am currently working with Apache Camel and using the **Micrometer** component for metrics. I have added the necessary dependency, but I am facing an issue where the metric is not showing up in the /actuator/prometheus endpoint.

```
    Spring boot version: 3.1.4.
    Java version: 17.      
    Apache camel spring boot dependency: 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-micrometer-starter</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these properties to your app.property file

- management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
- management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
- management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
- management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
- management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true

Comment: I added properties but the problem is still present

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using camel-observation instead:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-observation-starter</artifactId>
  <version>x.x.x</version>
  <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
```

You also need to annotate your main class with `@CamelObservation`.

This will provide you metrics using Micrometer and much more in case you need them (i.e.: distributed tracing).

Comment: it's only valid for spring boot version 3+ ! ?

Comment: Yes. Fyi: Spring Boot 2.7 (2.x) has reach the end of its OSS support timeline so you should be on 3.x already: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support